# Python multiprocessing pool: limiting both maximum running time and number of processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

There have been a lot of posts for having a capped running time for the Python multiprocessing pool, like [Python multiprocessing module: join processes with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063877/python-multiprocessing-module-join-processes-with-timeout) and [python multiprocessing pool timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711840/python-multiprocessing-pool-timeout). However, none of the solutions also feature the limit of maximum processes, for example, by using `multiprocessing.Pool(n_processes)`. Any hint on how to have both a capped running time and a maximum number of processes for the pool? Thanks!

Comment: Are you serious? `multiprocessing.Pool(n_processes)` does limit the maximum number of processes.

Comment: `multiprocessing.Pool(n_processes)` does limit the maximum number of processes but doesn't feature a capped running time.