# Any concurrent.futures timeout that actually works?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, timeout, concurrent.futures

Tried to write a process-based timeout (sync) on the cheap, like this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def call_with_timeout(func, *args, timeout=3):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as pool:
        future = pool.submit(func, *args)
        result = future.result(timeout=timeout)
```

But it seems the `timeout` argument passed to [future.result](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result) doesn't really work as advertised.

```
>>> t0 = time.time()
... call_with_timeout(time.sleep, 2, timeout=3)
... delta = time.time() - t0
... print('wall time:', delta)
wall time: 2.016767978668213
```

OK.

```
>>> t0 = time.time()
... call_with_timeout(time.sleep, 5, timeout=3)
... delta = time.time() - t0
... print('wall time:', delta)
# TimeoutError
```

Not OK - **unblocked after 5 seconds**, not 3 seconds.

Related questions show how to do this with thread pools, or with [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.alarm). How to timeout a process submitted to a pool after *n* seconds, without using any _private API of multiprocessing? Hard kill is fine, no need to request a clean shutdown.

Comment: I'm seeing the expected timeout length in preliminary tests.

Comment: @user2357112 Interesting - `time.sleep` was just chosen as an MCVE and might have platform-dependent quirks - could you try it with a busy-looping function, or something dumb like `10**100000000`?

Comment: ...oh, I think I see. I think *cleaning up* the pool is blocking.

Comment: I see the 5 second wall time for the second test on Ubuntu. What OS are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [`pebble`](https://pypi.org/project/Pebble/).

Its `ProcessPool` was designed to solve this exact issue: enable timeout and cancellation of running tasks without the need of shutting down the entire pool.

When a future times out or is cancelled, the worker gets actually terminated effectively stopping the execution of the scheduled function.

Timeout:

```
pool = pebble.ProcessPool(max_workers=1)
future = pool.schedule(func, args=args, timeout=1)
try:
    future.result()
except TimeoutError:
    print("Timeout")
```

Example:

```
def call_with_timeout(func, *args, timeout=3):
    pool = pebble.ProcessPool(max_workers=1)
    with pool:
        future = pool.schedule(func, args=args, timeout=timeout)
        return future.result()
```

Comment: I was about to add examples myself. You were indeed faster :)

Comment: Yeah, I actually had something going with pebble already.  I was kinda hoping there was some api in stdlib...  but +1 anyway

Comment: I built `pebble` exactly because of that. The stdlib Pool implementations `concurrent.futures` and `multiprocessing` are all a bit too optimistic.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised you're the pebble author.  Thanks for your work!

Comment: Is the timeout killing subprocess behavior only with ProcessPool or even without the ProcessPool as in the second example here: https://pypi.org/project/Pebble/?

Comment: Adding another comment since I can't edit existing one. I am using pebble's ProcessPool but it looks like the processes which timeout never get killed and stay in background forever. Is this expected behavior or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: For anyone looking for a complete usage example of Pebble, I found the [first one in the readthedocs](https://pebble.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pools) to be more helpful than the one on PyPI.

Answer (score 3):

The timeout is behaving as it should. `future.result(timeout=timeout)` stops after the given timeout. *Shutting down* the pool still waits for all pending futures to finish executing, which causes the unexpected delay.

You can make the shutdown happen in the background by calling `shutdown(wait=False)`, but the overall Python program won't end until all pending futures finish executing anyway:

```
def call_with_timeout(func, *args, timeout=3):
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
    try:
        future = pool.submit(func, *args)
        result = future.result(timeout=timeout)
    finally:
        pool.shutdown(wait=False)
```

The Executor API offers no way to cancel a call that's already executing. `future.cancel()` can only cancel calls that haven't started yet. If you want abrupt abort functionality, you should probably use something other than `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to wait for pending futures to finish executing. Just want them killed (which is why using a subprocess and not a worker thread in the first place).

Comment: @wim: Answer expanded.

Comment: So is the answer essentially "there is no high-level API to do it"?  Perhaps this is because `concurrent.futures`/`multiprocessing` must also work on Windows where SIGKILL is not necessarily available...

Comment: @wim Would this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494001/how-can-i-abort-a-task-in-a-multiprocessing-pool-after-a-timeout