# How to Identify and Report Python Multiprocessor Issues

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I'm running a Python 2.7 script that processes many thousands of files and documents, using 16 processors to process jobs queued in a JoinableQueue.  We've run into an issue where some of the file/folder data being processed is corrupt.  All jobs seem to eventually complete, but the ones with the corrupt data take a really long time.  The long-running processing actually happens in an external library, so once it starts, the process needs to wait for the library method to finish.

I don't want to kill the long-running processes, but when a job is taking longer than 30 seconds or one minute, I'd like to log a message about which job is working longer than expected.

The main code is blocked with queue.join().  How can I monitor the state of the processing?  Is the best approach to start an async background timer process for each time a document job is processed, or is there a better way?

I've removed most of the code, but a skeleton of what we're doing is the following:

```
queue = mp.JoinableQueue()

for doc in doclist:
    queue.put(doc)

processes = [mp.Process(target=doprocessing, args=[queue]) for i in range(nb_workers)]
for p in processes:
    p.start()

queue.join()
for p in processes:
    p.terminate()

def doprocessing(queue):
    while True:
        item = queue.get()
        try:
            processDoc(item["id"])  
        except:
            pass
        queue.task_done()

def processDoc(id):
    # Do processing
    pass
```

Comment: Relevant [any-concurrent-futures-timeout-that-actually-works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54011552/any-concurrent-futures-timeout-that-actually-works)