# stopping a process using python

Tags: linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

i need to stop a specific process(in the script that included) on command that is running in the background on my raspberry pi using python...what code should i use?

i tried different os commands but it didn't worked

```
path = "/home/pi/Desktop/fm_transmitter-master/"
os.chdir(path)
args = ["sudo", "python", "PiStation.py", "-f", "96", "song.mp3"]
pi_station = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE
```

i need to stop this procces on command using python code

Comment: Welcome to SO! How does `pi_station.terminate()` or `pi_station.kill()` work for you? Also, your code is truncated; did you use the `shell=True` or `shell=False` argument?

Comment: no i didnt used shell at all......this is all the code

Comment: Well, this doesn't compile as is--at the very least, there's a missing closing paren. Let me know about `terminate()` and `kill()`, and if either of those work...

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522032/robust-way-to-manage-and-kill-any-process/56290192#56290192